# Android Studio does't check/highlight Kotlin Room DAO queries when string occupies more than 1 row

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-sqlite, android-room, android-architecture-components

When I'm trying to break query for better readability/comprehension it stops being checked by IDE. 
This occurs on Android Studio 3.2 canary 16 and 3.1.2 stable, kotlin version 1.2.41.

[image]

When Room DAO is java class/interface everything works fine.
Is it possible to have the same checking/highlighting for 2+ rows queries in kotlin as in java?

[image]

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs

Comment: For future: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80553973 https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-13233

Comment: I just started dabbling with Kotlin today and noticed this when I converted my Room DAOs. Kind of a shame that your bug report was closed as a duplicate of a less detailed report posted nearly a year later. That other one was closed as fixed last week.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50892856/kotlin-inject-android-room-sql-language-on-multiple-line-queries). The raw string solution works and is clean.

Answer (score 3):

This is supposed to be resolved in AS 3.6, but, for now, the workaround noted at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/130141151#comment3 does the trick.