# Kotlin - Inject Android Room SQL language on multiple line queries

Tags: kotlin, android-room

How can I get multi-line queries to be injected? It works on Room with Java classes, but does Kotlin support this as well?

E.g. I have 2 queries here, and only the top SQL query (1 line) gets injected.

[image]

I tried to follow the [steps in this guide](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/7g9246/dont_forget_to_inject_android_room_sql_language/) but could not find the required settings.

There is an issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-13636 which  suggests this is fixed, but I'm not sure how to implement the fix.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can use a **raw string** which is more readable anyway:

```
@Dao
interface ItemDao {
    @Query("""
        SELECT * FROM Item
        WHERE Item.id = :id
        """)
    fun loadItemById(id: Long): LiveData<Item>
}
```

Comment: Sure this works? Using version 2.1.0-beta01 of Room is dosen't... Haven't tried in other versions so this might in that case be a regression... (???)

Comment: What does mean "doesn't work"? Throws an exception? Doesn't compile?

Comment: I just tried it and "raw string" works on Android Studio 3.6.2 with room 2.2.5. By work I mean that the SQL syntax checking and highlighting.has the same behavior as with a one line SQL. Splitting the string via concatenations doesn't get checked or highlighted. Thanks.

Comment: This one works for `@Query`, but doesn't work for `execSQL()`, as of Android Studio 4.1.1 and everything latest